# How to add Date using dynamic field in system.xml file?

Tags: magento2

I want to add Date control in system.xml file using dynamic field...
as shown in below image
[image]

Does anyone have any idea? How can I do this?
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Try this code**

**Vendorename/Modulename/etc/adminhtml**

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="test" translate="label" sortOrder="201">
            <label>Test Date</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="test" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Test</label>
            <tab>test</tab>
            <resource>Vendorename_Modulename::test</resource>
            <group id="general_setting"
                   translate="label"
                   type="text"
                   sortOrder="10"
                   showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                  <field id="date_fieldname"
                       translate="label"
                       sortOrder="20"
                       showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <backend_model>Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
                    <frontend_model>Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\DynamicFieldData</frontend_model>
                </field>
              </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Vendorename/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config**

**ArraySerialized.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value as ConfigValue;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class ArraySerialized extends ConfigValue
{

    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if (isset($value['__empty'])) {
            unset($value['__empty']);
        }
        $encodedValue = $this->serializer->serialize($value);
        $this->setValue($encodedValue);
    }

    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if ($value) {
            $decodedValue = $this->serializer->unserialize($value);
            $this->setValue($decodedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**Vendorename/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config**

**DynamicFieldData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class DynamicFieldData extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    private $holidaysRenderer;
    private $dateRenderer;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {

        $this->addColumn(
            'select_date',
            [
                'label' => __('Date'),
                'id' => 'select_date',
                'class' => 'daterecuring',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'date_title',
            [
                'label' => __('Content'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'style' => 'width:300px',
            ]
        );

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('MoreAdd');
    }

    protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row): void
    {
        $options = [];
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);

        $script = '<script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "mage/calendar"], function (jq) {
                    jq(function(){
                        function bindDatePicker() {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                jq(".daterecuring").datepicker( { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" } );
                            }, 50);
                        }
                        bindDatePicker();
                        jq("button.action-add").on("click", function(e) {
                            bindDatePicker();
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>';
        $html .= $script;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***